# Como fazer UPDATE com AJAX + PHP + PDO

Tags: ajax, pdo

Estou tentando realizar um Update com AJAX e PDO, porém não estou conseguindo. Já tentei de várias formas e não consigo ajustar o código. Ele está afetando apenas o último id cadastrado. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor? Segue o código:

```js
function uptade_cat() {
    
    var valor_update=$("#valor_update").val();
    var id_cat_update=$("#id_cat_update").val();
    var nome_categoria_update=$("#nome_categoria_update").val();
 
 var id_cat = $(this).attr("id_cat");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "caixa/categoria_uptade.php",
            data: {nome_categoria:nome_categoria_update, valor:valor_update, id_cat:id_cat_update},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
    $('#valor_update').find("input[name='valor_update']").val()
    $('#nome_categoria_update').find("input[name='nome_categoria_update']").val()
    $('#id_cat_update').val(data.id_cat_update);
    $('#alert_message3').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Sucesso!</strong> Categoria Atualizado.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
   $('#categoria_uptade_form').reload(); 

    
            },
            error: function() {
    $('#erro').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Erro!</strong> Ocorreu algum problema ao atualizar categoria.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
       
           
            },
        });
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">

  <div class="card-header">
                                <strong class="card-title">Editar Categoria</strong>
                            </div>
   <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table">
              <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="td-actions">Registro</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Categoria</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Valor</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Editar</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<?PHP
$select = "SELECT * from caixa_categoria ORDER BY id_cat DESC ";

  
  try{
   $result = $conexao->prepare($select);   
   $result->execute();
   $contar = $result->rowCount();
   if($contar>0){
    while($mostra = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
?>           
                  <tr>
     <td> <?php echo $mostra->nome_categoria;?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $mostra->categoria;?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $mostra->valor;?> </td>
                    <td class="td-actions text-center"> <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cotegoria_<?php echo $mostra->id_cat;?>"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Editar</td>
    </tr>
     
<?php
}  
   
   }else{
    echo '<div class"alert alert-danger">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                      <strong>Aviso!</strong> Não há post cadastrado em nosso banco de dados.
                </div>';
   }
   
  }catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e;
  }
     
  ?>   
                
                  
                
                </tbody>
              </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>


<!-- Modal -->
<?php 

   $result = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * from caixa_categoria');  
   $result->execute();
    while($mostra = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
  
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="cotegoria_<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Categoria: <?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?> (<?php echo $mostra['categoria'] ?>)</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="categoria_uptade_form" name="categoria_uptade_form">
     <div class="form-row">
      <input type="hidden" name="id_cat_update" id="id_cat_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" > 
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Nome Categoria</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_categoria_update" id="nome_categoria_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Valor</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_update" id="valor_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['valor'] ?>">
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
   
        <div id="alert_message3"></div>
        <div id="erro"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="uptade_cat()">Atualizar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

categoira_uptade.php

```
$id_cat= $_POST['id_cat'];
$nome_categoria= $_POST['nome_categoria'];
$valor= $_POST['valor'];

$stmt = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE caixa_categoria SET nome_categoria=:nome_categoria, valor=:valor WHERE id_cat=:id_cat");

$stmt->bindparam(':id_cat', $id_cat);
$stmt->bindparam(':nome_categoria', $nome_categoria);
$stmt->bindparam(':valor', $valor);


if($stmt->execute())
{
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}
```

Comment: Não pode repetir id's.

Comment: @Sam Pode me explicar melhor ?

Comment: Dentro do while vc está repetindo diversos id's, como por exemplo o `id="id_cat_update"`. Sendo assim, o JS vai pegar sempre o primeiro id que encontrar na página.

Comment: @sam Você tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso de modo correto ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está repetindo vários id's, o que é incorreto em HTML. Um id serve para identificar um elemento na página de forma individual, assim como o CPF diferencia uma cidadão de outro.

O que você pode fazer é remover as id's repetidas (como por exemplo, a `id="id_cat_update"`) e pegar os elementos pelo atributo `name` (explico mais abaixo).

Mas é preciso também enviar um `this` para a função `uptade_cat()` para poder saber de qual modal a gente vai pegar os dados. Então coloque o `this` aqui:

```
onclick="uptade_cat(this)"
```

E na função você recebe o `this` como parâmetro (usei a letra `m`):

```
function uptade_cat(m) {
```

Pronto! O `m` representa o botão que chamou a função. Com isso fica fácil de pegar qualquer dado dentro da modal, porque o botão está dentro da modal.

Então, você irá pegar a modal onde está o botão desta forma:

```
function uptade_cat(m) {
   var m = $(m).closest("div.modal");
```

Acima eu converti o `m` (que era o botão) na modal onde está o botão. Logo, dentro da função, a variável `m` será a div da modal.

**Pegar os valores:**

Tendo a modal em mãos (variável `m`), você pode buscar dentro dela qualquer elemento usando o método `.find()`, e não precisa usar id's para isso (por isso falei antes para remover os id's repetidos). Você pode buscar um input, por exemplo, pelo atributo `name`:

```
var valor_update = m.find("[name='valor_update']").val();
```

É só fazer isso com todas as variáveis dentro da função para pegar os valores `.val()` dos elementos que você quer.

Comment: TOOOP, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado!!!!

Comment: as mensagem de erro e sucesso não aparecem mais. Tenho que identificar que está no modal, parecido com var m = $(m).closest("div.modal"); ?

Comment: Sim, mas troque por class: `class="erro"`, aí vc acha com `$(m).closest("div.modal").find(".erro");`